# insert using for in vb

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

```
Dim i as integer 
For i = 0 to 365
    sqlinsert.InsertCommand="insert into cashdate (date) values (getdate()+'" & i & "')"
    sqlinsert.Insert()
Next
```

---

getdate is a function in the database that returns the datetime of now
i have an error that says conversion failed when converting date or time  from character string

what to do now ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are implicit casting the `GETDATE()` to a varchar like this:

```
getdate()+'1'
```

You probably want to have

```
getdate()+" & i & ")"
```

Instead of:

```
getdate()+'" & i & "')"
```

Comment: that really helped me out ... but i always thought that when i concatenate i have to put ' ' between ""
i think ' ' represents string , right?

Comment: Yes it representing a string. But in this case you are using a datetime. The if you want to add a day to that you need to format it as an integer.

Comment: um sorry i'm new here , i did now :)